# UPS Mudule with REST not working at all 2.4.6

Tags: shipping, ups

I've attempted to use the UPS module with REST and can't seem to get it to work.  First, I'm not certain where and what credentials to enter in the UPS section under shipping.  There are three fields to fill, account number (6) digits, ID and password.  I have a key and secret key along with an account number from UPS.  I've tried all different variations, also trying my UPS login information.  Can't seem to get it to work.  FedEx works fine but my shipping prices are better with UPS. I've tried it with all versions using REST.